# Vue.js : transform v-model data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am iterating through `items` in a checkbox.  When I click on an item, it pushes each of those objects into the `newItem` array.  However, I'd like to transform the new data in `newItem` to just be an array like this:  `["age: 55", "age: 25"]...` how can I transform the data going into `newItem` to be shaped like that?

```
items: [{name:"Billy, age: 55, permission: true}, {name:"Mike, age: 25, permission: false}],
newItem: [],

<v-checkbox v-for="item in items" v-model="newItem"></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property called `selectedAges` based on the `newItem` property :

```
computed:{
  selectedAges(){
    return this.newItem.map(item=>{
      return "age: "+item.age;
  
   })
  }
}
```